# C# - How to verify text that can't be found in HTML code but is on the page

Tags: c#, html, selenium, verify

I'm trying to verify text that's on the screen, but not currently visible in the HTML code of the page.  I'm running Selenium with C# programming language. Below is the line of code on the HTML page that has the element I'm trying to assert against.

```
 <input id ="TransferStatus" class="TransferStatus" name="" readonly="readonly" value="" type="text"></input>
```

In the tag 'Input' (which is a rectangler box that has a value in it), there should be text between the tags.  However, as you can see in the above code, there is no text to check for that.  On the page, it'll have text saying it's 'Complete' though.

Is there any way to very that text even if I can't see it in the HTML code of the page?

Comment: `input` does not have closing tag - it is [void element](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/syntax.html#void-elements)... Not really clear what do you mean "text between the tags".

Comment: Sorry, I guess I meant to say in general when trying to use the '.Text' method.  Thanks for clearing that up for me, I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get attribute value instead of get text:

```
string textValue = driver.FindElement(By.Id("TransferStatus")).GetAttribute("value");
```

Comment: But the issue I'm currently having is that when the element is present or not present, the 'name' and 'value' attributes are still null.  Nothing is in that line of code, even though on the actual page, it'll show a value.

Comment: @Tscott If the value attribute of the input element is null, I think the text is not from that element; there may be another element on that input element.

Answer (score 0):

In  your case I think `value` is not updated. I will recommend you to create easy extension method :-

```
public static string InnerHtml(this IWebElement source) {
            return source.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: How would I implement that into my script?  Would the source just be the location of the web element? And would it be Absolute Xpath or something else?

Comment: Its an extension method, Copy and paste in your code and it will be available in IWebElement object.   for more information http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension